# Overlay banner doesn't show up on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the website in question:
*site removed*

As you can see at the top right of the homepage there is a banner that overlays the graphics on the site. It shows the Rolex brand so customers can see the affiliation. Unfortunately, when you view it on a mobile device the overlay banner doesn't show up at all and I have no idea why.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in your bootstrap.css

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #overlay {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The problem is not the mobile device but the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #overlay {
        display: none;
    }
}
```